# Neighbor joining algorithm using ete3 and manhattan distance matrix condensed as a dictionary

Tags: bioinformatics, phylogeny

My algorithm is as follows:

```
while len(t.get_leaves()) > 2:
    min_dist = float('inf')
    for node1 in t:
        for node2 in t:
            if node1 != node2:
                dist = sum(distance_dict[(leaf1.name, leaf2.name)] for leaf1 in node1.get_leaves() for leaf2 in node2.get_leaves()) / (len(node1.get_leaves()) * len(node2.get_leaves()))
                if dist < min_dist and dist > 0:
                    min_dist = dist
                    min_node1 = node1
                    min_node2 = node2
    new_node = t.add_child()
    new_node.add_child(min_node1)
    new_node.add_child(min_node2)
    new_node.dist = min_dist / 2.0
    if min_node1.is_leaf() and min_node1 in t:
        t.remove_child(min_node1)
    if min_node2.is_leaf() and min_node2 in t:
        t.remove_child(min_node2)
```

And I get the following error:

```
TreeError: 'child not found'
```

I am performing the algorithm on a dictionary created from a distance matrix, thus containing all combinations of manhattan distance given all the 84 individuals I have at my disposal.

I used the ete3 Tree data structure to create nodes for each of the 84 individuals and a leaf id.
This leaf id is then used in combination with the known distances to perform the Neighbor Joining algorithm as seen above, however something goes wrong in the ultimate execution, and I can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please check out [tour], [ask] and [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Did I understand you right that your aim here is reproducing the NJ algorithm by yourself?